# Optimizing index creation

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, index-tuning

One thing that has bothered me for awhile is creating many many indexes for the one table where the query only differs slightly or contains many of the same columns.

An example case would be:

```
table1
--------------
id
state
first_name
last_name
city
phone
cat_id
```

Now, imagine the below queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state = 'WA' AND cat_id = 124;
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state = 'WA' AND cat_id = 124 AND first_name = 'bob';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE state = 'WA' AND cat_id = 124 AND phone = '12345' AND first_name = 'bob';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE city = 'seattle' AND last_name = 'jones' AND phone = '12345';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE city = 'seattle' AND cat_id = 124 AND phone = '12345' AND last_name = 'jones';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE city = 'seattle' AND cat_id = 124 AND phone = '12345' AND first_name = 'bob' AND last_name = 'jones';
```

Normally I would just create an index for each type, unless there are far too many combinations. However, this generally feels like I am just creating one big mess, and on large tables, substantially increasing the `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` times.

Is there a better method to handle things like this?

**Note:** I don't have a table like this and I am also aware of leftmost indexing, this is purely an example case.

Comment: The first think that strikes me is that you should be using BIT columns for the yes/no values (not CHAR(3) or however you're storing YES/NO). It also seems like you could normalize this table differently - instead of having a column for each clothing type (and having to change the schema and all of the interface code every time you add a clothing type), have a separate table altogether for the clothing. You haven't given us a lot to go on in terms of how the data is used except for this one query pattern, but can you let us know if you're open to different design or if you're stuck with this?

Comment: (Well, whatever MySQL's equivalent to BIT is, surely there is no need to actually store "yes" instead of 1, and "no" instead of 0.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand As I said, I don't have a table like this, it is purely an example; and no, if I was creating a table like this, I wouldn't design it like this, and if I was I would probably use `enum` as the data type.

Comment: I have updated my question with a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, indexes shine in cases where the criteria given will narrow down the data set significantly.

For example, if you have a table of 10 million rows, and the few criteria will narrow it down to say 100 rows, then using proper indexes will help greatly.

So, in your hypothetical table, I would a few composite keys lead by the almost compulsory criteria.

1. index on (state, city, first_name, last_name)
   *people typically search by state*
2. index on (city, first_name, last_name)
   *else they should know the city name*
3. index on phone
   *if they know phone, usually the rest seldom matters*

While googling to see if someone else gives a good explanation, I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/15631388-5664-4c07-a2e8-18377e184e30) for your read as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Found some good info via the link you provided! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indexing the columns that only have `yes` and `no` values (cardinality of 2) would never get use. You would quickly subject table1 to table scans. Index merges would be out of the question : See [Combining columns in index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27097/combining-columns-in-index/27111#27111)

In the given table, note that you could separate the clothing types from the person

Here is your table. Let's call it `person`

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    state CHAR(2),
    jacket CHAR(3),
    coat CHAR(3),
    shoes CHAR(3),
    raincoat CHAR(3),
    sweater CHAR(3),
    pants CHAR(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY (state)
);
```

Let's create two tables

Here is one to hold types of clothing

```
CREATE TABLE articles_of_clothing
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    article VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO clothing_types (article) VALUES
('jacket'),('coat'),('shoes'),('raincoat'),('sweater'),('pants');
```

Here is one to hold types of clothing associated with a person

```
CREATE TABLE clothing
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    person_id INT NOT NULL,
    article_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY person_article (person_id,article_id),
    KEY article_person (article_id,person_id)
);
INSERT INTO clothing (person_id,article_id)
SELECT A.id,,B.id FROM person A,
(SELECT id FROM articles_of_clothing WHERE article='jacket') B
WHERE A.jacket='yes';
INSERT INTO clothing (person_id,article_id)
SELECT A.id,,B.id FROM person A,
(SELECT id FROM articles_of_clothing WHERE article='coat') B
WHERE A.coat='yes';
INSERT INTO clothing (person_id,article_id)
SELECT A.id,,B.id FROM person A,
(SELECT id FROM articles_of_clothing WHERE article='shoes') B
WHERE A.shoes='yes';
INSERT INTO clothing (person_id,article_id)
SELECT A.id,,B.id FROM person A,
(SELECT id FROM articles_of_clothing WHERE article='raincoat') B
WHERE A.raincoat='yes';
INSERT INTO clothing (person_id,article_id)
SELECT A.id,,B.id FROM person A,
(SELECT id FROM articles_of_clothing WHERE article='sweater') B
WHERE A.sweater='yes';
INSERT INTO clothing (person_id,article_id)
SELECT A.id,,B.id FROM person A,
(SELECT id FROM articles_of_clothing WHERE article='pants') B
WHERE A.pants='yes';
```

Let's remove the clothing columns from the person table

```
CREATE TABLE person_new LIKE person;
ALTER TABLE person_new DROP COLUMN jacket;
ALTER TABLE person_new DROP COLUMN coat;
ALTER TABLE person_new DROP COLUMN shoes;
ALTER TABLE person_new DROP COLUMN raincoat;
ALTER TABLE person_new DROP COLUMN sweater;
ALTER TABLE person_new DROP COLUMN pants;
INSERT INTO person_new (id,state) SELECt id,state FROM person;
ALTER TABLE person RENAME person_old;
ALTER TABLE person_new RENAME person;
DROP TABLE person_old;
```

Now that they are separated, let's look at your queries. We'll use just the first one.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE pants = 'yes' AND sweater = 'yes';
```

How can you accomplish this under the new design? Do it in stages

- Create a Table to collect person_ids from each pass
- Query the clothing table for all person_ids that have `pants` and collect them
- Query the clothing table for all person_ids that have `sweater` and collect them
- Count how many have person_id written twice
- Join all person_ids found twice back to person table

Here are those steps

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE queryids (person_id INT NOT NULL,KEY (person_id));
INSERT INTO queryids
    SELECT B.person_id FROM
    (SELECT id article_id, FROM articles_of_clothing WHERE article='pants') A
    INNER JOIN clothing USING (article_id) B
;
INSERT INTO queryids
    SELECT B.person_id FROM
    (SELECT id article_id, FROM articles_of_clothing WHERE article='sweater') A
    INNER JOIN clothing USING (article_id) B
;
SELECT B.* FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) rcount,person_id
    FROM queryids GROUP BY person_id
    HAVING COUNT(1)=2
) A LEFT JOIN person B;
```

Since you only have 6 articles of clothing this may not be the best solution. If you have over twenty articles of clothing, the Query Optimizer stands a better chance of using indexes. I say this because when the Query optimizer has to read more than index entries for more than 5% a table, the Query Optimizer gives up an does a full table scan.

I have given this rule-of-thumb as a root cause to many index searching misadventures:

- `Dec 11, 2012` : [How do I force a JOIN to use a specific index in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30139/how-do-i-force-a-join-to-use-a-specific-index-in-mysql/30140#30140)
- `Jun 18, 2012` : [Why does MySQL only sometimes use my index for a range query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19400/why-does-mysql-only-sometimes-use-my-index-for-a-range-query/19407#19407)
- `May 07, 2012` : [MySQL EXPLAIN doesn't show 'use index' for FULLTEXT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/mysql-explain-doesnt-show-use-index-for-fulltext/17545#17545)
- `Mar 22, 2012` : [Why does MySQL choose this execution plan?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15437/why-does-mysql-choose-this-execution-plan/15438#15438)
- `Jan 18, 2012` : [MySQL status variable Handler_read_rnd_next is growing a lot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/mysql-status-variable-handler-read-rnd-next-is-growing-a-lot/10905#10905)
- `Oct 20, 2011` : [In MySQL, should I add an index even if the query that scans the table is only ran once a month?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/in-mysql-should-i-add-an-index-even-if-the-query-that-scans-the-table-is-only-r/7020#7020)
- `Jul 12, 2011` : [MySQL very slow query when changing one WHERE field despite no index/key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3780/mysql-very-slow-query-when-changing-one-where-field-despite-no-index-key/3788#3788)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent post, but as I said I don't have a table like that nor would I design one like that, it was merely an example to illustrate many columns. I have now updated my question with a better example.